# Iphone freehand crop sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, graphic

I would like to take an image of a person using camera and then edit the image in an app. The app should have a feature to crop(preferably freehand crop) the person only leaving the background so that I am able to use the person on different backgrounds. I am not sure how to do the cropping part.. kindly suggest a method to do this in ios?